# How to attach keyboard to tinyX server

Tags: linux, arm, buildroot

I have compiled root file system for my arm development board with the help of buildroot.My rootfs contains TinyX server and match-box as window manager.Then i have launched the x server by this script below.

export DISPLAY=:0

X -wr -keybd keyboard -mouse mouse & (TinyX)

matchbox-session &

The problem that i am facing is keyboard not working in the TinyX server.
The TinyX server is producing the following error message 
"driver Linux console keyboard wanted to post scancode 57 outside of [0, 0]!"
for all key press and release.
But mouse is working fine.

Can anybody please give me some suggestions to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Env: QEMU qemu-system-arm ver 1.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 host.
Guest: kernel 3.2.21

Emulated board: ARMv7l Verstatile Express

Root filesystem with X support, etc built using Buildroot ver 12.08; TinyX X server.

Ran qemu with:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel <kernel> -drive file=<rootfs-ext2-img>,if=sd -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0 init=/myinit.sh" -serial stdio -net nic,model=lan9118 -net user
```

Once the guest is running, we have a console window and a graphical qemu window (which is empty to start with).

In the guest console window:
Start X:

```
Xfbdev :0 -keybd evdev,,device=/dev/input/event0 -mouse evdev,,device=/dev/input/event1 &
```

Then load up xterm, etc.

I use a simple script, here it is:

```
# cat Xstart.sh 
#!/bin/ash
unset USERNAME LOGNAME

echo Setting up X server ..
# kill any stale instance
kill $(ps |grep Xfb|head -n1|awk '{print $1}') 2> /dev/null
export DISPLAY=:0

# How to determine 'mouse' dev?
# dmesg shows :
# input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/mb:kmi0/serio0/input/input0
# input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/mb:kmi1/serio1/input/input1
# QEMU_ARM_BR / # ls /sys//devices/mb:kmi1/serio1/input/input1
# capabilities/ id/           name          properties    uniq
# device@       modalias      phys          subsystem@
# event1/       mouse0/       power/        uevent
# Can see the only 'event' file is 'event1', so we use it!

Xfbdev :0 -keybd evdev,,device=/dev/input/event0 -mouse evdev,,device=/dev/input/event1 &

sleep 1
echo "Running fluxbox & xterm .."
DISPLAY=:0 xterm 2> /dev/null &
DISPLAY=:0 fluxbox 2> /dev/null &

echo "### Please wait a bit for X to initialize & come up ... ###"
sleep 3
echo "Press [Enter] to use this console..."
read

#
```

Notice the hint on how to determine mouse, keyboard device: look up dmesg output..